# Is it possible to make map-server subscribe to image

Tags: navigation, mapping, ros-kinetic, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to make map_server subscribe to sensor_msgs/Image

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286088/is-it-possible-to-make-map-server-subscribe-to-image/) by [rajagrwl](https://answers.ros.org/users/34243/rajagrwl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-03-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These are different message types -- so you can't directly connect them. You could write a node that subscribes to sensor_msgs/Image and outputs nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid. You'll also need to create the data for nav_msgs/MapMetaData (which clearly won't exist in the image).

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2018-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0